# Mysql: Update all or first select and after update?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 2 column: id and count. Count is exclusive OR (only one of them can be 1 at same time). I need to update a row with count = 1 and need to put the previous count 1 at 0.

I think two strategies:

1) Do a select on the table, find the row at 1.
Update it at 0.
Update the row that i want be at 1.

2) Global update the table at count 0.
Update the row that i want be at 1.

In the first case i do 3 query but "small".
In the second case i do 2 query but one of them is "big".

Which strategy is better?

Comment: Whatever takes less time overall I guess. In both cases you are doing two updates, but one extra select is there in first one. So just see if that changes time taken or not.

Comment: You could combine the two steps of strategy (1): "Do a select on the table, find the row at 1. Update it at 0" into one step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply swapping the value on two rows you could do it in a single query.

eg.

```
+----+-------+
| id | count |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 0     |
| 2  | 0     |
| 3  | 1     |
+----+-------+
```

Update using a self join:

```
update myTable a, myTable b set
    a.`count` = b.`count`,
    b.`count` = a.`count`
where a.id = '2'
and b.id = '3'
```

The result:

```
+----+-------+
| id | count |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 0     |
| 2  | 1     |
| 3  | 0     |
+----+-------+
```

If you want to target a specific row, you can do that also.
eg. row with id 1 should have a count of 1, and whatever currently has a count of 1 should be reset back to 0.

```
update myTable a, myTable b set
    a.`count` = 1,
    b.`count` = 0
where a.id = '1'
and b.`count` = '1'
```

Comment: I always test before I post :)

Comment: the last example is exacly what i am looking for. i didn't remember that i can call 2 times the same table. TNX